# Windows 10 Universal Remove Lock Screen Image

Tags: windows-10, win-universal-app, windows-10-mobile

I had an application that would set the lock screen image. However, I no longer support this on my Win 10 app and want to remove the image. Is there a way, in code, to remove the lock screen image or set it back to the system default?

Answer (score 0):

You can retrieve current lock screen image and save it. After that you can rollback to previous state when you will want.

This feature available only for Windows 10 Desktop (as I know). You need add `Windows Desktop Extensions for the UWP` for you project. More information by [link](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/cdndevs/archive/2015/07/27/uwp-extensions-and-apiinformation.aspx).

After that you can save current `LockScreen` image before you manipulations with `LockScreen`:

```cs
if (ApiInformation.IsTypePresent("Windows.System.UserProfile.LockScreen"))
{
    var fileName = "originalLockScreenImage";
    //check is file exists
    var originalLockScreenFile = await ApplicationData.Current.LocalFolder.TryGetItemAsync(fileName);
    if (originalLockScreenFile == null)
    {
        var currentImageStream = Windows.System.UserProfile.LockScreen.GetImageStream();
        var tempFile = await ApplicationData.Current.LocalFolder.CreateFileAsync(fileName, CreationCollisionOption.OpenIfExists);
        using (var fileStream = await tempFile.OpenAsync(FileAccessMode.ReadWrite))
        {
            await currentImageStream.AsStream().CopyToAsync(fileStream.AsStream());
        }
    }
    else
    {
        //rollback if you want
        await Windows.System.UserProfile.LockScreen.SetImageFileAsync((IStorageFile)originalLockScreenFile);
    }
}
```

Comment: Hi! For which programming language it's this snap of code?

Comment: @NetVicious for C#

Comment: I'm trying to create a simple solution in Visual Studio for creating one command line exe which changes the lock wallpaper. Can you tell me which SDK I need to install to have Windows.System.UserProfile ?

Comment: @NetVicious If you want use `Windows.System.UserProfile.LockScreen` add to your solution `Windows Desktop Extensions for the UWP`.  Look at my post above.

Comment: Thx for the info. The solution should be a Universal application, and C# doesn't allows Universal console applications. I want to create a simple exe to change the lockscreen wallpaper within a command line.

Answer (score 0):

The [`UserProfilePersonalizationSettings`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.system.userprofile.userprofilepersonalizationsettings.aspx)  provides the method [`TrySetLockScreenImageAsync`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.system.userprofile.userprofilepersonalizationsettings.trysetlockscreenimageasync.aspx) to set the lock  screen  image. But there is no method to remove the lock screen image or set it back to the system.

In Windows 10 desktop, it uses the [`Windows spotlight`](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/mt621549(v=vs.85).aspx) app for the lock screen pictures by default. As I know, we can not set the lock screen with `Windows spotlight` by API.

In Windows mobile 10, the lock screen is different from Windows 10 desktop. It use the `My picture` by default.

As a workaround method, you can launch the lock screen setting, and let the user chooses the `My picture` or `Windows spotlight`. No matter in Windows 10 desktop or in Windows mobile 10, the uri of the lockscreen settings is same.

For example:

```cs
bool result = await Launcher.LaunchUriAsync(new Uri("ms-settings:lockscreen"));
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming that you want to return your platform to it's original state or thereabouts. Select the settings icon (the gear shaped thing), and go over to "Personalization." After hitting that you'll see on the left side a vertical list of options one of which is "Lock screen." The option bar under the "Background option" has a little drop down expansion arrow. If all is well, you'll have three options, one of which should be "Windows Spotlight." If you want that, take it. If you want a different picture, browse. Hope this was useful and helpful.